# Symfony 2 - Portal features (out of the box)

Tags: php, symfony

I want to start developping an online portal with Symfony 2 for a specific business case. User can register, save some data and schedule some executions.

But before I will start to invent all features by myself I tought I would ask the community if there is a starter-package Symfony 2 with some core functionalities (MVC) for an simple online portal:

- Registration
- Login (BN/PW, FB-Login, ...)
- Login reset
- User management for admins

Maybe with some optional functionalities for users like:

- Profil edit
- Avatar upload
- PW change

If there is a starter-package I could save a lot of time and start developing my business logic faster.

Thanks,
rjgamer

Comment: There is FOSUserBundle, HWIOauthBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is no 'out-of-box' complete Symfony2 application which run immediatly after installation.*

**BUT**

Symfony2 has a concept for this way. The concept call **'Bundle'.**
Bundle is used for speedly building application with Symfony2 Framework.

With lot of bundle in application symfony2, you can easily and more faster construct an application. More configuration and parameters but less implementation of code.

The most popular example of this concept and your requirements is the bundle **FOSUserBundle** which help you to install a full system of user for your application without implementing yourself lot of basics concepts of management users.

You must search bundle for which of your requirements.
You find for almost anytime a bundle for your requirements.

Perhaps search a github project which contain all of this popular bundle in symfony application.

Welcome to big world of Symfony and try to find your favorite bundle !

Comment: Thx for your detailed explanation!